# Finding the row for a cell in jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I am a newbie in programming and I am currently learning JQuery. I have a question that if I have a button in a column attribute and when I click a button in a cell for that attribute I want to find what is the value of unique id for that cell i.e, if if my attribute name is approved whose value I toggle between Yes and No via button click, I want to fetch the value of the unique id say name attibute in JQuery, so that I can update the value for approved using an AJAX call.

```
<table>
<th>S.no</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Submitted by</th>
<th>Approved</th>
<tr>
<td>1.</td>
<td>XYZ</td>
<td>21-3-04</td>
<td>NO <input type = "button" onclick = "toggle()" value = "click"/></td></tr>
.
.
.
</table>

<script>
function toggle(){
//I want to fetch the value of the Name attribute for the row in which my button was clicked. and later I want to call an ajax call to a url that will consist of Update query.
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us some code

Answer (score 1):

First up what you are calling an "attribute" is an "element".

Secondly get rid of the inline `onclick=` attribute.

Then, using some appropriate jQuery methods:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table td input[type='button']").click(function () {
        var name = $(this).closest('tr').children().eq(1).text();
        // do something with name
        alert(name);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EVuGV/1

That is, bind a click handler to all of the input button elements in the table (ideally you'd give your table an `id` attribute and use that, e.g., `$("#idOfTable td")`). Within the function, `this` will be set to the particular button that was clicked, so from there you can use jQuery's DOM navigation methods to go up to the containing tr element and then within the tr's children select the second and get its text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="click"/>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
      $("table td input[type='button']").on('click',function () {
         console.log($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();)
      }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/28/

```
 $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
});
```

Please see the example.

Note: I wrote the code to get the "Name" value of that row only.

Comment: Note that if the table is contained inside another table `parents('tr')` will get the containing tr elements from both tables... A more appropriate option is `.closest('tr')`.

Comment: Thanks Mr.nnnnnn. Now i changed my code to get the value from .parents() to .closest()